# Make a VPN connection only for RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vpn, firewall, pptp

I am connecting to a cisco VPN router via PPTP on my windows 7 Ultimate machine.  Like most VPN's, it connects just fine but also redirects all of my traffic through the VPN.  I really only need RDP access when I use this specific VPN and maybe later down the road a few other services.

My local network is using 192.168.1.0/8 and the remote network is using 10.10.10.0/8.

Is there any way to make this vpn conneciton only use RDP (program or specific ports) via windows firewall or something else?

Comment: "`192.168.1.0/8`": is that a thing? Perhaps you mean the opposite (inverted bits), `192.168.1.0/24`, same for `10.10.10.0/8` -> `10.10.10.0/24`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network" in Properties for the VPN connection?
It is hidden away in Networking, IPv4 Properties, Advanced, IP Settings.

Comment: I tried that but then I don't have any DNS entries for the servers I am trying to connect to.

Comment: But it works if you use the IP address?

Comment: THe PPTP server can send a name server address for the connection. You can check with ipconfig /all if there is one.

Comment: Yeah IP's work but it is easier to remember DNS names rather than IP's

Comment: Of course, but it relevant to know when trying to help. If the name server IP is there, try the fully qualified name.

Comment: If it doesn't, perhaps your router does not pass UDP, but it can be told to do so. If you're doing this just for yourself, you can put the host names in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, or save a rdp file for each hosts and pin them  to the taskbar

Comment: Is your router your internal name server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up split tunneling.  With split tunneling you can direct all traffic destined for 10.10.10.0/8 to use the tunnel and all other traffic to use your default gateway.  You are not splitting based on what application you are using but where the traffic is headed.  I don't know that you can do specific ports unless you also use some kind of proxy.

Also note that if you don't administer the Cicsco VPN router, you may not be able to this.

Comment: I am the administrator of the router but I see no option for that.  I am using the RV180W which is fairly limited compared to the higher end models